# Checkout : Change Saved addresses Dropdown to Radio Button

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

can anyone help me change a field on the Checkout page (when the customer is logged in and he has an address) from a dropdown list to a radio button list ?

I am trying to edit this function:

```
$this->getAddressesHtmlSelect('billing')
```

found on:

```
code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Abstract.php

$select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(\'core/html_select\')
                ->setName($type.\'_address_id\')
                ->setId($type.\'-address-select\')
                ->setClass(\'address-select\')
                //->setExtraParams(\'onchange=\"show_new_address(this.value)\"\')
                ->setValue($addressId)
                ->setOptions($options);

            $select->addOption(\'\', Mage::helper(\'checkout\')->__(\'New Address\'));
```

My problem is that I can’t find the file where I can change the dropdown list into a radio button list.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can override  this file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Html/Select.php